# "inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8" error while trying to write a degree symbol (invisible character)

Tags: symbols, unicode

No matter how I try to do it I always get the following error :

> ! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:­ not set up for use with LaTeX.

I have tried using ­­­`$^{\circ}$`, `\deg`, `\textdegree`, pasting the ° symbol directly, to no avail.

Here is the header of my document, in case one of those could be causing the errors :

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
%\FrenchItemizeSpacingfalse
\frenchbsetup{CompactItemize=false}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
```

Comment: I had the same issue. In my case it was an issue due to a misleading character in my bibdesk library. After exchange and a new run with BibTex everything was fine again.

Comment: A quick solution is to use the "Zap Gremlins" feature in the fantastic (and free to use) [TextWrangler](http://www.barebones.com/products/textwrangler). This removes non-ASCII, control and NULL characters. **IF** you want a simple ASCII input file this will save you lots of time looking for invisible characters.

Comment: As noted by Antal Spector-Zabusky at the very end of his answer, compiling with `xelatex` should solve the issue.  Just make sure to remove the `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` line.

Comment: You don’t need `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` in any engine. It’s been the default since 2018.

Comment: In XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, though, you would want to `\usepackage{fontspec}` instead of `fontenc` and `lmodern`.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

If you're getting literally that error—with no visible character after the `\u8:`—then what's probably happening is that you have some sort of invisible or space unicode character in your document.  For instance, on my Mac, if I hit option-space, I get a non-breaking space, which gives an error that looks like that.  You also might have some other character; a zero-width breakable space, for instance.  If you copied and pasted your error, looking at the source of this page indicates that you might have a soft hyphen in your source (Unicode character `0xAD`, representing a valid hyphenation point but not typeset unless there's a word-break).  Thus, find the line it's occurring on, and comb through that line until you find it.  Retype it if necessary, but a good editor should let you find it.  Once you delete it, then your first three methods should work.

When I use your header (commenting out `\frechbsetup`, which doesn't seem to exist, and using `\documentclass{article}`), `$^{\circ}$` renders as a largeish circle in the superscript position, `$\deg$` renders as the upright text "deg", and `\textdegree` renders as a smaller circle.  A literal `°` doesn't work by default.  To make it work, you can use `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{B0}{\textdegree}`.  This tells `inputenc` to treat the Unicode character `0xB0`, the `°`, as though it were `\textdegree`, which is what you want.  You could also use this to see if your problem is the soft hyphen; insert `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{AD}{\Huge [ICI]}` to get the text `[ICI]` rendered into your document in huge letters wherever there's a soft hyphen.  (Of course, if there's some other invisible character, you'll just get the error.)

Also, although I've never used it, you could try using XeLaTeX instead of PDFLaTeX; it has full UTF-8 support out of the box.

Comment: Indeed, an invisible character seemed to be the source of my problem. Thanks!

Comment: No problem.  I remember how befuddled I was the first time I ran into this problem; I'm glad I could help someone else out with it.

Comment: @AntalS-Z Is there a way to detect which symbol is causing this error ? It is giving this error in the first line where there is plain text. Thanks.

Comment: @Anusha: Not that I can think of off the top of my head – depending on your editor, you could (a) retype the line, (b) step through it with the arrow keys until you hit something strange, (c) turn on some sort of "show invisible characters" setting, or (d) put the file through some sort of shell filter like `cat -v` or `xxd` to see where the first wrong character is.

Comment: Showing invisible characters doesnt help in Notepad++. Any tips using emacs ? Or which editor might help with it ?

Comment: @Anusha: In Emacs, if your document is mostly in ASCII (that is, the basic 26 characters of the Latin alphabet in upper- and lower-case, the 10 digits, and a handful of punctuation), then you could search for a non-ASCII character: `C-M-s [ -~]` (`C-M-s` searches for a regular expression, and `[ -~]` looks matches the printable ASCII range).  This will match most possible culprits, in addition to tabs and newlines.

Comment: In my case, it was ``ﬂ`` instead of ``fl``, a product of copy-pasting.

Comment: Man it really bothers me that there isn't a general solution to this type of problem

Comment: Ah, actually, I think I spoke too soon: just run your text through this: https://pteo.paranoiaworks.mobi/diacriticsremover/ to clean all the annoying invisible characters (or just google "remove unicode characters")

Comment: I was going to ask for suggestion of which text editor would you recommend for macos, since Notepad++ is not an option here. 
I ended up using `cat -v` as @AntalSpector-Zabusky suggested. If you are one of those guys ending up here, in my case having this `?M-^IM-^H1` instead of `\approx` caused me the trouble.

Comment: +1 for the suggestion to use XeLaTeX!

Comment: @Anusha: In emacs, you can also try `M-x set-buffer-file-coding-system RET us-ascii` and emacs will complain that it cannot encode the non-ascii chars. Type `C-g` and click on one of the chars listed in the warning to go to it.

Comment: I use the package "Highlight Dodgy Chars" to make them appear in Sublime. 
 https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Highlight%20Dodgy%20Chars

Answer (score 50):

Using

```
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
```

instead of `[utf8]` solved the problem for me.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13067/utf8x-vs-utf8-inputenc...

Comment: Adding to Paul Gaborit's comment: This "solves" the problem but introduces ut8x, which is undesirable. This answer should not be upvoted.

Comment: it doesn't work me:-(

Comment: And I'm getting `Package biblatex Error: Incompatible package 'ucs'. \begin{document}`

Comment: my pdf is rendering perefectly even with this error. should i still worry about it?

Comment: Just introduces other problems, such as issues with ščřžýáí in the reference name. Do not use.

Answer (score 23):

`\usepackage{textcomp}` is missing.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\begin{document}
 °
\end{document}
```

Comment: Adding `textcomp` worked for me, but so did using `$^{\circ}$` in the text. Which is cleaner?

Comment: It depends on how often you are going to be using the character.

Comment: As of 2020, `textcomp` is integrated into the LaTeX kernel, and no longer needs to be included explicitly. So your solution, which was correct when you posted it, is now applied automatically.

Answer (score 5):

I got this error after copying a word from my browser and pasting it into my editor. Just retyped it an the problem was solved.