# Unicode char \u8:动 not set up for use with LaTeX

Tags: errors, unicode

I m generating one chinese report and getting following error.

```
Unicode char \u8:动 not set up for use with LaTeX.
```

i m using including following packages.

```
\usepackage[LGRx,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
```

How to fix this pblm?

Comment: See also [“inputenc Error: Unicode char `\u8`” error while trying to write a degree symbol (invisible character)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4268/5764).

Comment: Please, add a minimal example.