# Error: Unicode char \u8 with french document

Tags: errors, languages

I have recently picked a file in asian laguage. When I have maked the necessary change in order to take a file in french laguage, I have this error:

```
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8: not set up for use with LaTeX.
```

Here is the code source

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[TS1,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,hmargin=2cm,vmargin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath, amssymb,amsthm, graphicx}
\usepackage[francais]{babel} \usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\newtheorem{definition}{\textbf{Definition}}

\begin{document}

\section{Chaos de Wiener}

\subsection{Décomposition en Chaos de Wiener}

On se donne: \begin{itemize}   \item Un espace de Hilbert séparable
$H$, muni du produit scalaire $\langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle_{ H}$,
qui induit une norme $\| \cdot \|_{ H}$   \item  Un espace de
probabilité complet $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb P)$. \end{itemize}


\begin{definition}[Processus Gaussien isonormal] \label{def:1} On dit
que le processus  $W = \{ W(h); h \in  H\}$  défini sur  $(\Omega,
\mathcal{F}, \mathbb P)$,  est un \textit{processus Gaussien
isonormal} sur  $H$ si $W = \{ W(h); h \in  H\}$ est   constitué par
une famille de v.a.r  gaussiènne centrée  vérifiant la relation: Pour
tout $h, g \in H$,  on a

$$E [ W(h) W(g) ] = \langle  h, g \rangle_H$$

\end{definition}

\end{document}
```

Well, I do not know if my questions are understandable and acceptable. 
Thank you in advance (and thank you to  Gonzalo Medina and cfr and other  for these answers).

Comment: See this answer. Perhaps it addresses your issue?

http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/4270/6908

Comment: And what is `\E`?

Comment: When I install `texlive-lang-french` and remove `\E`, the example compiles for me.

Comment: try using `utf8x` insted of `utf8`

Comment: Make sure that your editor has saved the file as UTF-8 not iso-8859-1 or similar codepages. Also unrelated note that you should never leave a blank line before a displayed equation (TeX will insert a spurious blank paragraph line if you do) and you should use `\[` not `$$` in latex/

Answer (score 1):

I already had this problem, it turned out that I had iso-8859-1 characters in my text file.

I would advise you to check that your file is, indeed, in UTF-8 and, if not, to convert it to UTF-8 (eg. with `convert` or any similar software).

Also, trying a dyadic search through the text might help to localize the faulty character.

Comment: The problem persists nevertheless the proposed advises. Help!

Comment: @Zbigniew are you sure your file is in utf8? If it is stored in iso-8859-1 and you don't want to change that, change `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` to `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}`  but changing the document to utf8 is better really

Comment: I thank all for their helps. I have delete the word si in text and rewrite than the problem is solve. I don't know why.

Comment: It was because 'si' contained a non UTF-8 character (some characters are just invisible). Next time you encounter this problem try to be sure that no iso-8859-1 character is in the file. And, by the way, once you have converted your file to UTF-8, you can rewrite the 'si' as you wish (as long as it does not include iso-8859-1 character).