# How to fix Package inputenc Error: "Unicode char \u8:ï¿½ not set up for use with LaTeX."?

Tags: input-encodings

I get following error when running pdflatex in TeXstudio: "Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:ï¿½ not set up for use with LaTeX. \end" on the last line of my document:

```
\printbibliography
\end{document}        <- error comes here
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please provide a compilable code of your document. It should be as short as possible while showing your error. If the error is part of the bib, we need to see the culprit entries as well. Like this, we would be guessing around.

Comment: You probably have a spurious U+FFFD character somewhere.

Comment: A similar issue, regarding incompatible (spurious) character encoding, can be found with more details in "**inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8 error while trying to write a degree symbol (invisible character)**" (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4268/inputenc-error-unicode-char-u8-error-while-trying-to-write-a-degree-symbol).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I managed to fix this on my own.

The problem was that my .tex file used utf-8 encoding, but my .bib file used ANSI-encoding. The error presented itself, when I added a bibliography entry which contained an apostrophe. To fix this I converted the .bib file to utf-8 encoding with Notepad++ and removed the files produced by pdflatex (aux, .bbl, .bcf etc.) and then ran pdflatex again.

Comment: [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/413422/31839) might be helpful to some people coming here, not sure which bib entry is the problem.