# ! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char ​ (U+200B)?

Tags: unicode, input-encodings

```
\begin{description}

 \item[Public : ] Dans les clouds ​​publics,
 \item[Privé : ] Dans les clouds ​​privés,

\end{description}
```

I don't know why I got the error mentioned in the question knowing that I worked with this syntax before.

How can I solve this ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please post a full compilable example (MWE) to help us help you. Have you loaded `inputenc` (maybe with an option other than `utf8`)?

Comment: thanks @TeXnician, for the packages  I used this : 
`\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}   
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}  `

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are four characters U+200B (ZERO WIDTH SPACE) between `clouds` and `publics`/`privés`. A simple fix is to remove the space with the `p` and retype them. Maybe, these characters were introduced by the editor or some copy/paste operation.

Comment: Well I can't see where are the spaces, there is only one.

Comment: @Sendja Nope. Move the cursor to the  right/left with direction keys (not with the  mouse) and count the keystrokes to pass from the "s" to the "p" and viceversa. Only two or maybe some more?

Comment: @Sendja Copy the string “clouds ​​privés” from your question (or from your input file) and paste into a website like https://r12a.github.io/uniview/ (and click on the down arrow), to see for yourself. Or just delete all the spaces and add one normally.

Comment: I ran into this problem following a copy and paste from a document written in word. I copied the entire text into notepad++ and used notepad++ to toggle the text encoding. Problem solved without looking for the offending stray invisible character.

Answer (score 6):

This is one of the top hits for U+200B and LaTeX, so I’ll post solutions here.

Take the following example:

```
\tracinglostchars=2
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}f​l f‌l fl\end{document}
```

In LuaLaTeX, it compiles to:

[image: Latin Modern font sample]

The first fl has no ligature because I inserted U+200B, a zero-width space.  The second has no ligature because I inserted U+200C, a zero-width non-joiner.  These might have been in the original source you copied from intentionally: a zero-width space could mean a potential line break, such as after a slash, and a zero-width non-joiner disables a ligature.  For example, the fi in Elfin or the fl in Halfling are (according to pedants like me) not supposed to be ligated, since they belong to different pieces of a compound word, but this is more common in some other languages.

If you try to compile it in PDFLaTeX, you will get the error message that brought you here:

```
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character ​ (U+200B)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.
```

There are several ways to fix it.

#### Clean Your Source by Hand

This is what most people on this site recommend.  Your editor might have a way to display special characters so you can delete them all. But really, isn’t this a job for a computer?

#### Clean Your Source with Perl

The following one-line Perl script will create a new source file with all zero-width spaces removed:

```
perl -CSD -pe "s/\N{U+200B}//gu" < U200B.tex > noU200B.tex
```

If it’s easier to remember, you could also write this as

```
perl -CSD -pe "s/\N{ZERO WIDTH SPACE}//gu" < U200B.tex > noU200B.tex
```

The `-CSD` option selects UTF-8 unconditionally, even if you don’t have UTF-8 as your default locale. The `-pe` option runs the given Perl script on the input file and prints to the output file. The `s` command does substitution, the `\N{...}` is a regular expression matching zero-width space, the empty field between `//` means replace with nothing, and `gu` means replace all instances globally in the unicode string.  Then, the `<` and `>` operators select the input and output files.

Either of these produce a file that compiles to:

[image: Computer Modern Font sample]

It’s also possible to automatically remove all characters outside a given subset.  The script

```
perl -CSD -pe "s/[^\p{Word}\p{Punct}\p{Symbol}\p{Mark}\p{PerlSpace}]//gu"
```

allows only the following: Unicode “word” characters, punctuation, symbols, accents and a few kinds of spaces.  It erases most invisible characters.  An even more restrictive version would be

```
perl -CSD -pe "s/[^\p{ASCII}]//gu"
```

This cleans out all characters but for the ASCII originally allowed in TeX (including `“` instead of double backtick).

And yes, we could replace zero-width space by something instead of nothing.  The script

```
perl -CSD -pe "s/\N{ZERO WIDTH SPACE}/{\\\\hskip 0pt}/gu; s/\N{ZERO WIDTH NON-JOINER}/{}/gu"
```

given the above MWE as input, produces the following output:

```
\tracinglostchars=2
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}f{\hskip 0pt}l f{}l fl\end{document}
```

#### Teach LaTeX to Understand Zero-Width Space

If the problem is that U+200B is “not set up for use with LaTeX,” but it’s equivalent to a TeX command—`\hskip 0pt` or `\hspace{0pt}` are zero-width spaces that prevent ligatures and enable a potential line break—we can set the character up to use that command.

```
\tracinglostchars=2
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{iftex}
\pagestyle{empty}

\ifTUTeX
  \usepackage{fontspec}
\else
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % The default since 2018
  \DeclareUnicodeCharacter{200B}{{\hskip 0pt}}
\fi

\begin{document}f​l f‌l fl\end{document}
```

Although the `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter` command is in `inputenc`, the LaTeX kernel has loaded it by default since 2018.  So, we could have skipped declaring it.

Answer (score 3):

These errors are hard to debug because if you have a long document then add a citation to a bibtex entry which has a non-unicode character, it's pretty hard to know which citation is the problem and where to look.

My solution was to do the following:

Run `pdflatex` or whatever, at the command line. This gives you the error in "console" format, like this:

```
Package inputenc Error: Unicode char ́ (U+301) not set up for use with LaTeX
```

I could then copy/paste the offending character (in my case, a weird accent on a bit of Spanish text) and paste it into the following command:

```
rgrep  ́
```

This allowed me to find the offending item in one of my .bib files and I could make the fix and get on with my life.